# bashのechoコマンドについて教えて下さい

Tags: bash, shellscript

bashのechoコマンドについて2点ほど教えていただきたく考えております。

1. ファイルの1行をechoした時にスペースをそのまま表示するにはどうしたらいいか
2. echoした文字列が画面からはみ出るとき自動的に折り返すようになりますが、これを抑止するにはどうするのか。

1つ目は例えば

```
      aaa    bbbbb
```

のような文字列を空白を残したまま表示したいです。しかしechoで表示すると空白が消えてしまいます。
以上2点について教えて下さい。

追記

```
#!/bin/bash

SPACE=90
FILE_NAME="hoge.txt"
COLS=`tput cols`
CURRENT_IFS=$IFS
IFS=''
while [ $SPACE -gt 0 ];
do
  while read LINE
  do
    j=0
    while [ $j -lt $SPACE ];
    do
      echo -n " "
      j=$(( j + 1))
    done
    printf "%s\n" "$LINE"
  done < $FILE_NAME
  SPACE=$(( SPACE - 1 ))
  sleep 0.5
  clear
done

IFS=$CURRENT_IFS
```

最終的なコード

```
#!/bin/bash

SPACE=100
FILE_NAME="thank_you.txt"
COLS=`tput cols`
while [ $SPACE -gt 0 ];
do
  while IFS='' read LINE
  do
    j=0
    while [ $j -lt $SPACE ];
    do
      echo -n " "
      j=$(( j + 1))
    done
    MARGIN=$(( COLS - SPACE ))
    echo "$LINE" | cut -b1-$MARGIN
  done < $FILE_NAME
  SPACE=$(( SPACE - 1 ))
  sleep 0.05
  if [ $SPACE -gt 0 ]; then
    clear
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1 ですが、行の内容が入っているシェル変数をダブルクォートで囲みます。

```
$ line='     aaa    bbbbb'
$ echo $line
aaa bbbbb
$ echo "$line"
     aaa    bbbbb
```

しかし、

```
$ line='-n'
$ echo "$line"
(何も表示されない)
```

という場合がありますので、できれば `printf`(bash の builtin function) を利用する方が良いかと思います。

```
$ line='-n'
$ printf '%s\n' "$line"
-n
```

2 についてですが、以下は `tput` コマンドを使う方法です。

```
$ echo $COLUMNS
82

$ line="$(seq -s '' 100)"
$ printf '%s\n' "$line"
123456789101112131415161... (snip) ...
...
...

$ tput rmam; printf '%s\n' "$line"
12345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940414243444
```

`tput rmam` を実行することで端末の `line wrapping` を抑止します。元に戻すには、

```
$ tput smam
```

として下さい。

**追記**

以下の部分ですが、

```
while read LINE
do
  j=0
  while [ $j -lt $SPACE ];
  do
    echo -n " "
    j=$(( j + 1))
  done
  printf "%s\n" "$LINE"
done < $FILE_NAME
```

以下の様に書くこともできます。

```
while IFS='' read LINE
do
  [[ $SPACE > 0 ]] && printf "%${SPACE}s" ' '
  printf "%s\n" "$LINE"
done < $FILE_NAME
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。これで文字列の中間にあるスペースは表示されました。しかし、先頭にあるスペースが表示されませんでした。

Comment: もしかして、read を使って行を読み込んでいませんか？ その場合は、`IFS='' read ...` などとして下さい。

Comment: 先頭のスペースは表示されましたがそれ以降のスペースが正しく反映されなくなってしまいました。

Comment: ファイルを読み込んでいる部分を追記していただけますか？

Comment: 本文の方に追加しました。

Comment: はい、ありがとうございます。`while read LINE` を `while IFS='' read LINE` にして、`CURRENT_IFS=$IFS` と `IFS=''` と `IFS=$CURRENT_IFS` を削って下さい。

Comment: やってみましたがやはりまだずれてしまいます。

Comment: そうですね、、、こちらで試すと内部のスペースもずれることなく表示されていますね。。。

Comment: もしかすると、表示する文字の影響かもしれません。

Comment: 違う文字列で試してみたところ、問題なく表示されました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。実装できました。

Answer (score 4):

`echo`は渡された内容を一切変更することなく出力します。空白が消えてしまうということは、そもそも`echo`に空白が渡されていません。
また`echo`には画面という概念もありません。画面からはみ出したくないのであれば、画面幅まで切り詰められた文字列を`echo`に渡す必要があります。

要するに、どのように`echo`を呼び出しているかの問題です。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。はみ出さずにするには、はみ出さないように文字列長を調整するしか無いということですね。

Answer (score 2):

`echo` の使い方や `printf` を使うべきなのは既にされている回答の通りですが、それ以外に提示されているスクリプトに気になった点があります。入力中のバックスラッシュが特別扱いされないように `read` に `-r` オプションを付けましょう。